# Spring annotations confusing and makes me don't get the full idea behind it

Tags: java, spring-mvc, annotations

Basically @Autowire and @Configurable do the same. What is the difference between these two annotation?

Please pardon me.

Comment: Have you read the Spring documentation? E.g. http://springindepth.com/book/aop-context-spring-configured.html

Comment: @tbsalling: Its not the Spring official documentation.  Are you talking about http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/?

Comment: Yes. That is the official docs. The link I provided is for a book that I use. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Configurable` allows you to inject dependencies without explicit bean definition while `@Autowire` used to inject the explicitly defined beans.